# Should I check if a row exists before deletion?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, optimistic-concurrency

I'm using Mssql as the db and EF4 as the ORM/DAL.
My question is about the following code:

```
public static void DeleteBuilding(int buildingId, int countryId)
{
    PlayerBuilding playerBuilding = new PlayerBuilding()
    {
        CountryID = countryId,
        BuildingID = buildingId
    };
    Entities.PlayerBuildings.Attach(playerBuilding);
    Entities.PlayerBuildings.DeleteObject(playerBuilding);
    Entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

If the row exists this works very well, **if not** I get an exception(*Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.*)
Should I make a round trip to the database to check if the row exists like this:

```
public static void DeleteBuilding(int buildingId, int countryId)
{
    PlayerBuilding playerBuilding = (from p in Entities.PlayerBuildings
                                     where p.BuildingID == buildingId && p.CountryID == countryId
                                     select p).FirstOrDefault();
    if (playerBuilding != null)
    {
        Entities.PlayerBuildings.DeleteObject(playerBuilding);
        Entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I think that extra round trip is kinda unnecessary because without the EF, with plain SQL I could simply delete the row with a single DELETE command.

What would be a better practice?

Answer (score 0):

That error is a side effect of Entity Framework's **optimistic concurrency**.

Basically, someone else may have deleted the record in between you retrieving it. Or maybe you have done something with the entity before that code.

Try running it in an isolate environment (e.g a unit test) to see if you still get the issue.

Yes, you could play it safe and get the record again, or you could use **[ObjectContext.Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx)**:

```
public static void DeleteBuilding(int buildingId, int countryId)
{
    PlayerBuilding playerBuilding = new PlayerBuilding()
    {
        CountryID = countryId,
        BuildingID = buildingId
    };

    try
    {
       Entities.PlayerBuildings.Attach(playerBuilding);
       Entities.PlayerBuildings.DeleteObject(playerBuilding);
       Entities.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
    {
       Entities.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, playerBuilding);
       Entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

On a side note - maybe it's because your method is **static**? How are you instantiating your context? I hope you're not using a singleton. :(

There is an **excellent** article on EF optimistic concurrency [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2008/09/05/optimistic-concurrency-updates-using-entity-framework-in-n-tier-and-n-layer-applications-part-2.aspx), which explains in further detail why you're getting that error, and what steps can be done to counter it.

Comment: thanks for the comment RPM, but this is not an optimistic concurrency problem. I'm working on a local developer computer, tried not static method, that not the problem neither. The context is instantiated using this method: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Managing-Entity-Framework-ObjectContext-lifespan-and-scope-in-n-layered-ASP-NET-applications.aspx. using the normal way to instantiate the context not changing anything.

Comment: Take a look at the article - the error in that article is exactly the same as yours. Did you try running the above code in a unit test (isolated)? Also - which way in that article you provided are you instantiating the context? (there are multiple methods in that article)

Comment: I've used the UnitOfWorkScope method but that not the issue. Even if I instantiate the context using the old way(MyContext context = new MyContext()) the same error is continue showing. I don't think it is related to concurrency, the error is showing because I'm trying to delete an object which do not exists in the context.

Comment: Okay. Did you try the "Refresh" method above in my answer? On a side note, should you even be calling this method in the first place when you know the object doesn't exist?